# how to protect php source code placed in sd card?

Tags: php, sd-card

My project is a combination of Java and PHP code.

The Java code is placed in a server, which is protected and other people cannot access it. But my PHP code is placed in an SD card. Data is fetched from the server and  displayed on a screen.

Now I want to protect my PHP code so that no one else could view it. Is there any way to protect it? Or is there any way to lock the SD card?

Comment: How does the PHP code run locally?

Comment: We are using a device which is connected to screen and it has that sd card. Server is installed in it, in which php code is placed. That device is connected to local network.

Comment: You could try obfuscating your code, but that's not quite the same thing...

Comment: Still it will not fully protect my code

Comment: You can use [Zend Guard](https://www.zend.com/en/products/zend-guard) for that.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search I found [Zend Guard](https://www.zend.com/en/products/zend-guard) as an appropriate solution for this problem. It helps in encryption as well as obfuscation.